# How to run multiple yarn commands with a bash script?

Tags: javascript, bash, yarnpkg

I have four separate repos that need to be run in this order:
They are all in the same directory. However what i currently have will only run the first one because as soon as the `yarn run dev` takes place, the `cd -` won't do anything.

```
cd "backend" && yarn run dev
cd -
cd "merchant" && yarn run dev
cd -
cd "frontend" && yarn run dev
cd -
cd "frontend2" && yarn run dev
cd -
```

Comment: Detatch the yarn process by using &, see https://superuser.com/q/178587/227355

Answer (score 0):

Run this from the parent folder:

```
npx concurrently --names "backend,merchant,frontend,frontend2" "cd backend && yarn run dev" "cd merchant && yarn run dev" "cd frontend && yarn run dev" "cd frontend2 && yarn run dev"
```